# Open image from external public directory through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Recently I am developing a file sharing application and I created a GridView, where the downloaded files are being shown. From this View, I would like to be able to open the default application through an intent, to open the whole file. Currently I am testing the app with only image files. All the files are downloaded to the external public directory this way:

```
File externalFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My application");
if(!externalFolder.exists()){
    externalFolder.mkdir();
}
...
File folder = new File(externalFolder, "Images");
if(!folder.exists()){
    folder.mkdir();
}
...
String filename = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileToDownload.getName() + "." + fileToDownload.getExtension();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
```

When the file is downloaded, I scan it with MediaScannerConnection.scanFile. The scan is successful, the picture is visible among other files in Photos app.

After the file is downloaded, I am able to extract a thumbnail in the adapter of the GridView, so I surely have a valid path to the file.

And where the fun begins: I tried to set an onClickListener to the GridView items in the adapter to be able to open the picture in Photos app this way:

```
listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if(new File(current.getPath()).exists()){
                Log.e("path", "valid");
            }else{
                Log.e("path", "invalid");
            }
            Log.e("path", Uri.parse("content://"+current.getPath()).toString());
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://"+current.getPath()), "image/*");
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The Intent is created successfully, I get the following in the log:

```
E/path: valid
E/path: content:///storage/emulated/0/My application/Images/best_picture_ever.jpeg
```

I have the option to choose among apps to open. When I select the app, it fails to open the image, like when it does not exist. All the 5 applications.

I tested this on my device with Oreo, and on two emulated devices with Nougat and Lollipop, all of them behaves the same way.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not creating a valid `Uri`. You cannot put `content://` in front of arbitrary things and have a useful `Uri`, any more than you can put `https://` in front of arbitrary things and have a usable URL.

[Use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve up this file.

Comment: Thanks, it actually solved my problem. I've seen this online a lot, I just was not aware that I need this approach to files which are in the public directory. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DávidBesenyei: On Android 6.0 and older, you probably can get away with `Uri.forFile()`. However, Android 7.0+ doesn't like that approach, and so `FileProvider` is the safer answer.

Comment: @DávidBesenyei, could you share your solution? I mean, to access a file in any public folder with a FileProvider.

Comment: @ARLabs Sorry, it would be difficult to present the exact solution, but the key was the usage of FileProvider. You can find a useful documentation about it on the Android developer site, the exact page is linked in the marked answer.

Comment: @DávidBesenyei, thanks. I know the usage of FileProvider to access a specific file in a specific folder. What I am trying to do is to refer a generic file in a generic public folder. Since the path is not known I cannot add it to file_path.xml, but it is a public file, so it should be possible to share it to others App.

Comment: @ARLabs Than thats a different story. In my case, i knew exactly the path of the file, I just missed the usage of FileProvider.